# How to reverse geocode latitude and longitude from location stored in CloudKit? - Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location, cllocation, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to figure out how to reverse geocode a `CLLocation` stored in `CloudKit`. I have the location stored in a record and I know it stores as latitude and longitude. [Here's my record. The latitude and longitude appear I just took them out for now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzRbG.png)
However I want to be able to make the location user-readable, so AKA reverse geocode it, to get the **city and state**. And I've looked on here so far but nothing on reverse geocoding the location I can store in `CloudKit`.

Here is my model:

```
class Peek: CloudKitSyncable {

    static let kType = "Peek"
    static let kPhotoData = "photoData"
    static let kTimeStamp = "timestamp"
    static let kTitle = "title"
    static let kText = "text"
    static let kLocation = "location"
    static let kCity = "city"

    let title: String
    let text: String
    let photoData: Data?
    let timestamp: Date
    var location: CLLocation
    var comments: [Comment]
    var photo: UIImage? {

        guard let photoData = self.photoData else { return nil }
        return UIImage(data: photoData)
    }

    init(title: String, timestamp: Date = Date(), text: String, photoData: Data?, comments: [Comment] = [], location: CLLocation) {
        self.title = title
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.text = text
        self.photoData = photoData
        self.comments = comments
        self.location = location
    }

    var recordType: String {
        return Peek.kType
    }

    var cloudKitRecordID: CKRecordID?

    convenience required init?(record: CKRecord) {

        guard let timestamp = record.creationDate,
            let photoAsset = record[Peek.kPhotoData] as? CKAsset,
            let title = record[Peek.kTitle] as? String,
            let text = record[Peek.kText] as? String,
        let location = record[Peek.kLocation] as? CLLocation else { return nil }
        let photoData = try? Data(contentsOf: photoAsset.fileURL)
        self.init(title: title, timestamp: timestamp, text: text, photoData: photoData, location: location)
        cloudKitRecordID = record.recordID
    }

    fileprivate var temporaryPhotoURL: URL {
        let temporaryDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
        let temporaryDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: temporaryDirectory)
        let fileURL = temporaryDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString).appendingPathExtension("jpg")

        try? photoData?.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)

        return fileURL
    }

}
extension CKRecord {

    convenience init(_ peek: Peek) {
        let recordID = CKRecordID(recordName: UUID().uuidString)
        self.init(recordType: peek.recordType, recordID: recordID)

        self[Peek.kTitle] = peek.title as String? as CKRecordValue?
        self[Peek.kText] = peek.text as String? as CKRecordValue?
        self[Peek.kTimeStamp] = peek.timestamp as CKRecordValue?
        self[Peek.kLocation] = peek.location as CKRecordValue?
        self[Peek.kPhotoData] = CKAsset(fileURL: peek.temporaryPhotoURL)
    }
}
```

I also have a LocationManager file as well:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = LocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var currentLocation: CLLocation?

    func requestCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        currentLocation = locations.first
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provides a method built into Core Location's `CLGeocoder` class.  [Here are the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder/1423621-reversegeocodelocation#).  If successful the completion handler will give you access to an array of `CLPlacemark`, so you can grab one of those and access whichever human-readable elements you need.  The names of the variables are pretty generic to cover locations all over the world, so you'll have to dig in a bit to find exactly what you need.  [Check the docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clplacemark) on `CLPlacemark` for exact details on the variables available to you.  In your particular case you'll need `locality` and `administrativeArea` for city and state, respectively.

Usage would be something like this:

```
let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { (placemarks, error) in
  guard let placemarks = placemarks, let placemark = placemarks.first else { return }
  if let city = placemark.locality, let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
    //Set your labels or whatever
  }
}
```